# injecting a variable using Java annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have created an annotation and I need to inject a variable (like in SLF4j log variable) using JAVA. Below is my code so far ...

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public  @interface ClassLevelAnno {
    public String testVariable = "abc";
}
```

And I am trying to use this annotation in the following class

package test;

```
@ClassLevelAnno
public class UsingTestAnno {
// I need to use testVariable defined in ClassLevelAnno class directly like follow.
    public void testMethod() {
        System.out.println(testVariable);
    }
}
```

As in the above class, I need to print the variable directly.
Why this class level annotation didn't inherit its fields.

Comment: Applying an annotation to a class is not the same as making the class inherit/implement an interface. `testVariable` is not accessible in `UsingTestAnno`. Further, *"injecting"* has a different (common) meaning from how you use it here, please look it up.

Comment: Annotations are like (special) interfaces (that’s why they are declared with `@interface`). So a variable declared within `@interface` still is implicitly `static final`. So you can access the value as easy as `ClassLevelAnno.testVariable`. Not that it makes sense, though; it doesn’t matter whether the using class has been annotated with that type nor is it injected in any way; you’ve just created a named constant.